# javascript cannot redirect in php

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I have created a form below and some javascript code in php, the it doesnt redirect to other pages.

```
<form method="post" name="for">
<?php

echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='go' onclick='fon1();'>";
?>
</form>

<?php
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "function fon1(){";
        echo "var k = confirm('Confirm Delete');";
        echo "if(k == true){";
        echo "window.location = 'http://www.google.com'; }";
        echo "else{ window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';} ";
        echo "}</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a **"return false;"** after calling **fon1();**

```
echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='go' onclick='fon1(); return false;'>";
```

Comment: Excellent, Its redirecting to page, May i know why? and how it worked.

Comment: the type="submit" bypassed your javascripts, in order to suppress the default behavior of the browser we must cancel the current behavior which is submit. You can also change the type to button, and remove the return false statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.href
```

instead of

```
window.location
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the type of your form buttom from "submit" to "button" :

```
echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='button' name='submit' value='go' onclick='fon1();'>";
```

try this!

Comment: With submit button, I need a value from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.location.replace to simulate a redirect (back button won't work)
or window.location.href so simulate a click

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<form method="post" name="for">
<?php

echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='button' name='submit' value='go' onclick='return fon1();'>";
?>
</form>

<?php
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "function fon1(){";
        echo "var k = confirm('Confirm Delete');";
        echo "if(k == true){";
        echo "location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; }";
        echo "else{ window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';} ";
        echo "}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="for">
<?php

echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='button' name='submit' value='go' onclick='fon1();'>";
?>
</form>


     <script type='text/javascript'>
        function fon1(){
        var k = confirm('Confirm Delete');
        if(k == true){
       document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
         }
        else
        { 
        document.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
        } 
        }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this..

```
<form method="post" name="for">
    <?php
    echo "<input type='text' name='text1'><input type='button' name='submit' value='go' onclick='fon1();'>";
    ?>
    </form>



 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function fon1(){
            if(confirm('Confirm Delete')) {;
                document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            }
            else { 
                document.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
            } 
        }
    </script>
```